# How to convert Array to ArrayList in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, arraylist

I have an array of `String` and I have to convert it to an `ArrayList`. Is it possible to do it in VB.Net?

Comment: This is a VB.Net question, not a VB6 question. There's no way you could do this in VB6 `Dim AList as ArrayList = New ArrayList(StrArry)` VB6 only supports parameterless constructors. I am editing your question, tags, etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim sArray() as String 'array of strings
...
Dim aList as ArrayList = New ArrayList(sArray)
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work since ArrayObject has to implement IList and the way array implements IList is a bit awkward

Comment: thanks but that one is Java...and VB6 does not have ToList() method for arrays

Comment: can't we do like this Dim AList as ArrayList = New ArrayList(StrArry); // StrArry will be our array of strings?

Comment: yes it works, update your answer and you get the points ;-) Thanks!